# How to pass data range to load crystal report

Tags: c#

I have created a 'report viewer' form. I inserted a panel on that form with two `DateTime` pickers (from date and to date) and one button to view the Crystal Reports report. And it works fine. I want to load the Crystal Reports form from another `datetime` picker form.

**Example:**
I have created two forms. Form-1 has two `datetime` pickers (From Date and To Date) and one button to view Report. And Form-2 has the Crystal Reports Viewer. I want to load the Crystal Reports viewer form (Form-2) through the Form-1.

How can i do this?

Comment: In conext of this issue what have you tried so far to achieve what you have mentioned in example

Comment: i write that c# language

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dataset as datasource for your report. Example:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets

You can for example put data from your database into the dataset. In your database query you might filter data according to the dates that the user chooses.